# Query SQL Server encrypted columns through python and show decrypted values

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, encryption, pyodbc, pymssql

I am trying to query a table (in an on premise database), which has some encrypted columns, in Python. I don't have any problem querying this data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Since I have a certificate, I just use Windows authentication to login, and in Additional Connection Parameters, I add "Column Encryption Setting = Enabled". This way I am able to see all the decrypted values.

In Python I am not able to do this. I have tried various parameters in the pyodbc library, but the values always show up encrypted.

What I have tried so far:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL 
Server};'
'Server=ServerName;'
'Database=DBName;'
'ColumnEncryption=Enabled;'
'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
'TrustedServerCertificate=yes;')

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL 
Server};'
'Server=ServerName;'
'Database=DBName;'
'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
'ColumnEncryption=Enabled;')
```

The values in the Python pandas dataframe still show up encrypted, something like

```
'\xee\x91\xghk\x00n\xk9.....
```

Comment: The two lines are identical. The only relevant setting is `ColumnEncryption` but you don't specify any certificate anywhere. The other settings control the TLS connection and use Windows Authentication

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I specify the certificate?

Comment: Which ODBC driver are you using? [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#enabling-always-encrypted-in-an-odbc-application) for the ODBC driver with `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}` it should be enough to just use `ColumnEncryption=Enabled;`. The latest driver version is 18

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is version 17. That worked, thanks a lot! I changed to Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} instead of Driver={SQL Server}

Answer (score 3):

`Driver={SQL Server}` (SQLSRV32.DLL) is the ancient SQL Server driver that ships with Windows. It dates back to the days of SQL Server 2000 and does not support many of the more modern SQL Server features.

Today's applications should use a more current driver like `Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` (MSODBCSQL17.DLL) or `Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server` (MSODBCSQL18.DLL).